# Jquery How to bind .is() and .on() events

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using checkboxes where the user can choose one or more options. I have managed to trigger an event if the checkbox has already been check (when retrieving info from the database). But I also want to trigger those same events when a checkbox is checked.

I have googled how to bind two events on jQuery but how can I do when it comes to an `$('#item').is(':checked')` and `$('#item').on('click', function(){})`.

Originally I am doing it like this within an `if` only for `.is(':checked')`:

```
if($('#item').is(':checked')){
//my stuff working fine so far
}
```

But I can't find out how to bind them inside the `if` operator. I have tried the following, but I can't make it work.

```
if($('#item').is(':checked') || $('#item').on("click",function(){})){
    //my stuff working fine so far
    }
```

Any ideas?

Comment: @MikeC Damn, it is indeed a super mega duplicate. Proceeding to delete this question. :-D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can bind the change event and trigger it on page load.

```
$('#item').on("change",function(){
    if(this.checked){
        //my stuff working fine so far
    }
}).trigger('change');
```